# Site not rendering in Internet explorer

Tags: css, jcycle

I have finally uploaded my first website. It is not close to being done, but I now get to see it rendered in all browsers and guess which ones are causing me to go crazy.... yup... Ie6 and Ie7

www.baseshamai.com is the website

Firstly I use multiple background on one elements using css3. So those are not showing up at all. What can I do for this?

Next is my Jcycle slideshow doesn't load. It works nicely in all other browsers and if you press portfolio you will see how it is suppose to work. But in Internet Explorer all the images load and are not getting "grabbed" by the slideshow plugin.
help?

Comment: You need to do a bit of research. Multiple backgrounds is a CSS3 property and is not supported for older versions of IE. There are many, many CSS3 properties which older IE versions do not support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Forget about IE6
2. Try to localize your cycle issue and ask a more detailed question, in the meantime, maybe this is your problem: [jQuery IE7 problem (using jQuery Cycle plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398278/jquery-ie7-problem-using-jquery-cycle-plugin)
3. Also, no CSS3 in IE6/7.

Comment: alright thanks. I think its working.... i can't tell.... all i have is browser labs at adobe. ill check tomorrow at work